# In a group of 15 players, how many ways can we select a team of 6 one of whom will be the team captain?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am getting two numerically different answers that seem equally correct.

$${15 \choose 6} \cdot 6 = 30030 \text{ and } 15 \cdot {14 \choose 5} = 18018.$$

Comment: Check the second one again.  Both give the same value.

Comment: $$k\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}.$$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it just arose from an error entering numbers into a calculator.